# How to hash a 3 dimensional index?

Tags: c#, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I'm trying to convert a coordinate made up of 3 integers into a single int (or similar) that I can use as a Key into a Dictionary and as a way of easily correlating data from disk with a coordinate in my program. My 3d coordinate system goes into negative values and has no set boundaries.

I've been researching hashing. I'm generally new to the concept, but as far as I'm able to tell this is the right direction to look in. Can anyone suggest a good algorithm or approach? Any way of encoding an arbitrary 3d coordinate to a unique, collision free id would put me on the right track.

Comment: Note that you don't need to hash to a unique value. It's more important for `Dictionary` that your hash values are evenly distributed.

Comment: Why dont you just Override Equals and GetHashCode and put the Key as the class object itself. The class object here being the instance that represents your 3d point. In the GetHashCode use the code that Chase has provided. And in the Equals just check for equality of the two points x, y, z

Comment: Could convert the triple into a string and hash the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, you can't hash a tuple of 3 arbitrary integers into one unique integer (that would be like trying to map every 96-bit integer into a unique 32-bit integer value), thus you can't get it to be "collision-free". However, a hashing algorithm just needs to produce well-distributed values. One very simple algorithm is to just XOR the 3 integers:

```
var hash = x ^ y ^ z;
```

One problem with this hash is that it gives the same value for (1, 0, 0) as for (0, 1, 0). A better approach might be:

```
var hash = unchecked(x + (31 * y) + (31 * 31 * z));
```

Hash functions can range from simple to very sophisticated. Most of the time, for something like putting a custom type into a dictionary, a fast, simple hash function like those described above will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was just what I needed to bump me over the threshold of basic understanding. I'm brand new to the forum, so can't vote up yet, but this is much appreciated. I'm marking it as the answer. If anyone has a fancy algorithm that works for the case I described, I'll happily take it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you might be over thinking this a bit. The 3 coordinates concatenated as strings with a delimiter, should be unique enough to use as a key.  This has the advantage of being able to extract the coordinates from the key if necessary:

```
    public static string MakeKey(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return a.ToString() + "/" + b.ToString() + "/" + c.ToString();
    }
```

Re: OP's comments:

Not sure what amount of data you're referring to but here's some code to ponder.  This makes a dictionary with 10 million items with each key being a random string 30 characters long and puts a random amount of those strings into a list.  One test I did pulled over 13,000 entries from the dictionary in 11 milliseconds:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> test1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int stopint = rnd.Next(2, (int)(Math.Sqrt(10000000)/2));
        List<string> check = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
            {
                sb.Append((char)rnd.Next(33, 256));
            }
            if(i % stopint == 0)
            {
                check.Add(sb.ToString());
                stopint = rnd.Next(2, (int)(Math.Sqrt(10000000) / 2));
            }
            test1.Add(sb.ToString(), i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < check.Count; i++)
        {
           int test = test1[check[i]];
        }
```

Comment: Good thinking. But my main concern would be the size of string based keys and the comparison speed. I'm working with very large data sets and this approach could get expensive. I'm hoping to generate compact keys that can be compared quickly.

Comment: To clarify a bit, I'm working with millions of entries in a real-time context. I'm continuously moving data between RAM and disk. That's where size becomes an important consideration.